# Swipe UIWebView to Advance to Next Blog Article

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsmutablearray, uigesturerecognizer

I have a couple blog apps out in which the RSS is parsed, and displays the article titles and dates in a TableView.  I have a RSSEntry class that I used from Ray Wenderlich's tutorials.  It parses all the different elements, and I then created a new string that includes HTML code and inserted in the article title, and contents into this new string of HTML.  My current code for selectedAtRowIndex in the TableView is:

```
RSSEntry *entry = [_allEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

         _webViewControllerplay.entry = entry;
```

Where _allEntries is the NSMutableArray, and _webViewControllerplay is the view controller with the webview.

What I would like to do is add a gesture recognizer to the webview's view controller, so that when I swipe left or right, it will go to prior article, or next article, without having to go back to the table view.  What are some ways that I could go about accomplishing this?  I understand I think that I will need to pass the entire Array, and then tell it which row it is currently on, and simply add or subtract to that when employing the gesture recognizers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure if I understood what you mean. My initial understanding was similar to @sergio - how to implement a gesture recognizer. But it seems you are looking for "how to design" your MVC (based on your comment to @sergio : "*...My issue is actually getting the array and everything passed over...*".

If so, here is a suggestion that might be helpful:

If you refactor your model, all entries, into its own class (subclass of `NSObject`) and declare some convenient properties, so that when, let's say, `EntriesViewController` pushes `WebViewController` into the navigation stack, instead of passing the entry itself, you can pass a pointer to the model. `WebViewController` can make its own inquiries to model.

Something like this diagram:

[image]

Hope this helps!

---

Edit:

Here is your model interface

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SARSSEntryModel : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *allEntries;
@property (nonatomic)         NSUInteger      currentEntryIndex;

@end
```

Here is model implementation

```
#import "SARSSEntryModel.h"

@implementation SARSSEntryModel
@synthesize allEntries   = _allEntries;
@synthesize currentEntryIndex = _currentEntryIndex;

// instantiate on-demand
- (NSMutableArray *)allEntries {
    if (!_allEntries) {
        _allEntries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"http://www.google.com", @"http://www.yahoo.com", @"http://www.bing.com", nil];
    }
    return _allEntries;
}
```

Here is EntriesViewController interface

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SARSSEntryModel.h"
#import "SAWebViewController.h"


@interface SAEntriesViewController : UITableViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) SARSSEntryModel *model; // this is your model
@end
```

Here is EntriesViewController implementation

```
#import "SAEntriesViewController.h"


@implementation SAEntriesViewController
@synthesize model = _model;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.model = [[SARSSEntryModel alloc] init];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}


- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [self setModel:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}


#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.model.allEntries.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell identifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.model.allEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    self.model.currentEntryIndex = indexPath.row;

    SAWebViewController *wvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WebViewControllerIdentifier"];
    wvc.model = self.model;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:wvc animated:YES];
}
```

Here is WebViewController interface

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SARSSEntryModel.h"


@interface SAWebViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) SARSSEntryModel *model;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@end
```

Here is WebViewController implementation

```
#import "SAWebViewController.h"


@implementation SAWebViewController
@synthesize webView = _webView;
@synthesize model = _model;



- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // for testing. to prevent conflict with one touch swipe
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(navigate:)];
    [self.webView addGestureRecognizer:swipe];
    swipe = nil;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [self setWebView:nil];
    [self setModel:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}


- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [self loadURL];
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}


- (void)loadURL {
    NSString *urlString = [self.model.allEntries objectAtIndex:self.model.currentEntryIndex];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
}


- (void)navigate:(id)sender {

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipe = (UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender;
    if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {

        if (self.model.currentEntryIndex < self.model.allEntries.count) {
            self.model.currentEntryIndex++;
        }
        else {
            self.model.currentEntryIndex = 0;
        }
    }
    else if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight) {

        if (self.model.currentEntryIndex > 0) {
            self.model.currentEntryIndex--;
        }
        else {
            self.model.currentEntryIndex = self.model.allEntries.count - 1;
        }
    }

    [self loadURL];
}
@end
```

Comment: Helps clear up what my issue is, just not sure how to implement still.  Basically thought I could have an NSInteger, and when row is selected, first get the number of what indexPath.row was selected.  Then, when it pushes the new view that holds a webview, I could tell it to load the array and display objectAtIndex:whatever the number of selected row was, then the swipe methods could work.  However, it keeps telling me incompatible trying to set type NSInteger to type NSInteger and returns null for the indexPath.row

Comment: here is the suggestion that was made in forum for getting the webview controller all it needs:

The other change you'll have to make is pass the WebViewController the entire array of feeds + the current index so that it has the info it needs to cycle through.

I can easily pass it the array of feeds, but not sure how to get the current index to it.  That is the main problem right now.

Comment: @user717452 I edited my answer to include some code snippets. Check that out.